# CloudWatch Logs Insights: converting strings to timestamp or datetime values

Tags: datetime, amazon-cloudwatch, datetime-format, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have log events in CloudWatch whcih have certain fields like `@timestamp` and `@message`.

`@timestamp` looks like this:

```
2022-08-09T08:49:51.971+02:00
```

and `@message` like this:

```
2022-08-09 06:49:49.376 INFO [xyz, 123abc456] xxxxxxx
```

I can extract the time in `@message` by using something like this:

```
| parse @message /(?<messagetst>.+) INFO/
```

What I want to do is to

1. convert the timestamp of `@timestamp` to UTC and a datetime format,
2. convert the `@message` `messagetst` to a datetime format,
3. substract `@timestamp` from `messagetst`.

Is this possible in CloudWatch and how can I do this?